# Ehrhart polynomial of lattice tetrahedrons in $\Bbb{R}^4$

Tags: combinatorics, discrete-geometry, polytopes

Let $\lbrace v_1 , v_2, v_3 , v_4 \rbrace \subset \Bbb{Z}^4$ be linearly independent, and denote by $P$ the convex hull of this set. Now, $P$ is a 3-polytope residing in four-dimensional space. What's the quickest way to compute the Ehrhart polynomial of $P$?

It seems that the examples that I've come across obtain Ehrhart polynomials for full-dimensional n-polytopes in $\Bbb{R}^n$.

Comment: A 3-polytope in 'general position' in 4-space wouldn't contain any lattice points. It would have to be specially placed to contain lattice points.

Comment: But wouldn't a lattice 3-polytope as described have an Ehrhart polynomial?